# How to use $scope.$watch on TypeScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I want to watch some element that binding to my component. this value may change(in another component) because he makes asynchronous call (promise).
Until now in JS I use `$scope.$watch` and when the binding element change he has a callback and I can continue with the value of element.

Example of JS:

```
$scope.$watch('myCtrl.myLayout', function (newVal, oldVal) {
    console.log('Layout is:');
    console.log(_this.myLayout);
});

angular.module('blocks.ui')
.component('myForm', {
    templateUrl: 'app/blocks/UI/form.html',
    controller: myForm,
    controllerAs: 'myCtrl',
    bindings: {
        myLayout: '='
    }
});
```

The question is how to implement the same thing using "clean" typescript syntax (I know that I can inject $scope and implement `$scope.$watch` on typescript in exactly same way).

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried it => `$scope.$watch('myCtrl.myLayout', (newValue, oldValue) => {
    // console.log(newValue);
});`?

Comment: @developer033 Thanks for your response but the question is how to watch element without inject scope(Is it at all possible?). What is the correct syntax in typescript for watch element.

Comment: so the question is not related to typescript at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is using typescript get & set

```
private _myLayout:any;

public get MyLayout() {
   return this._myLayout;
}

public set MyLayout(newItem: any) {
    this._myLayout = newItem;
    console.log('Layout is:');
    console.log(this.MyLayout);
}
```